# How can I get information about events that are bound to an element via live()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one `<a>` tag and bind to it two events.  How I can get information about other events attached to it?

The follow code explains what I mean:

```
<a href="#" id="sample" class="sample-cls">Click me</a>

$(function(){
    $('#sample').live("click", function(){
        sampleFunction();
    })
    $('.sample-cls').live("click", function(){
        // How to get information that to this link 
        // is attached another event, that run sampleFunction() ?
    })
})
```

Unfortunately, `$('#sample').data('events')` doesn't include the events bound via `live()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// List bound events:
console.dir( jQuery('#elem').data('events') );

// Log ALL handlers for ALL events:
jQuery.each($('#elem').data('events'), function(i, event){
    jQuery.each(event, function(i, handler){
        console.log( handler.toString() );
    });
});
```

See [this](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/things-you-may-not-know-about-jquery/)

Of course, this can be further enhanced to suit your needs.

Comment: I don't think that will work when the events are bound with `live` as in the question.

Comment: That is what I create new question about this ;) This code returns me an "undefined"